# C++ program works, but windows displays "program.exe has stopped working"

Tags: c++

This is my program:

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string K, R, S;
    string alfabet;
    int oznakaSlova = 65, i = 0, j;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        alfabet[i] = oznakaSlova;
        oznakaSlova++;
    }
    cin >> K;
    cin >> R;
    while(R.length() > K.length()) {
        K += K[i];
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while(R.length() > S.length()) {
        j = 0;
        int sifraSlovaKljuca;
        int sifraSlovaRijeci;
        int slovoSifre;
        while(K[i] != alfabet[j]) {
            j++;
        }
        sifraSlovaKljuca = j;
        j = 0;
        while(R[i] != alfabet[j]) {
            j++;
        }
        sifraSlovaRijeci = j;
        slovoSifre = (sifraSlovaKljuca + sifraSlovaRijeci) % 26;
        S += alfabet[slovoSifre];
        i++;
    }
    cout << S << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I *cin* both strings, and it *cout* me right thing, but after it display it, my windows make program.exe has stopped working. Also when I try this program on C++ Shell, it works perfectly, without any error. Should I do something about it, and what?

Comment: `alfabet[i] = oznakaSlova;` when alfabet only has 0 length is *undefined behavior*, which is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
alfabet[i] = oznakaSlova;
```

to

```
alfabet.push_back(oznakaSlova);
```

Strings don't grow just because you assign characters to them. You must use `push_back` or `resize` or similar to change the length of a string.